# How do I replace a dataframe column with variables from another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a `Indication` column in `dat` dataframe with the variables that correspond to the `Profile` column of the `ann` dataframe. The `Indication` column will have either `0/1` or `1/2` binary categorical variables for `Unaffected control` or `BP` variables, respectively.

```
library(dplyr)

phenocov <- dat %>% inner_join(ann %>% select("Database_ID", "Profile") %>% dummycov$PHENOTYPE==encode_binary(ann$Profile), by=c("FID"="Database_ID"))
```

Expected output

| FID | IID | SOL | C1 | C2 | Indication |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC13 | 1 | 0 | -0.02851720 | 0.00450319 | 1/2 |
| AC14 | 1 | 0 | -0.04220610 | 0.00394058 | 1/2 |
| AC15 | 1 | 0 | -0.01351050 | -0.03165270 | 0/1 |

`dat` dataframe

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(FID = c("AC13", "AC14", "AC15", "AC18", "AC19",
"AC1", "AC20", "AC21", "AC23", "AC24", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2",
"AC30", "AC32", "AC33", "AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC38", "AC42",
"AC43", "AC46", "AC48", "AC49", "AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53",
"AC54", "AC56", "AC57", "AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61", "AC62",
"AC63", "AC64", "AC65", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6", "AC70", "AC71",
"AC72", "AC74", "AC76", "AC77", "AC79", "AC80", "AC83", "AC84",
"AC86", "AC89", "AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC102", "AC103", "AC104",
"AC105", "AC16", "AC95", "AC96", "AC99", "DE10", "DE12", "DE13",
"DE14", "DE16", "DE17", "DE22", "DE23", "DE27", "DE36", "DE37",
"DE38", "DE39", "DE3", "DE40", "DE45", "DE46", "DE47", "DE4",
"DE50", "DE51", "DE52", "DE55", "DE57", "DE59", "DE7", "DE32",
"DE43"), IID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L), SOL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C1 = c(-0.0285172, -0.0422061, -0.0135105, 0.0335788,
0.00453814, -0.0196805, 0.00871406, -0.0359998, 0.00776039, -0.0152431,
-0.0157209, 0.0235421, -0.0292564, 0.000164687, -0.0104566, -0.0078923,
-0.011623, 0.0173727, 0.00327281, -0.0101589, -0.00564814, 0.0232102,
0.00209183, -0.0245178, 0.0295213, -0.0012923, 0.00775297, 0.019803,
0.00521905, 0.0143496, 0.0243968, 0.0403667, 0.0420627, -0.0234294,
-0.00923894, 0.00216892, -0.0174861, 0.000902948, 0.0250136,
0.131506, 0.036772, -0.0314508, 0.0014534, 0.0123288, 0.0152248,
0.030759, 0.029896, 0.0257204, -0.0132957, -0.00942661, 0.0286468,
0.0297961, -0.0225471, 0.0185018, -0.0103523, -0.00141674, -0.00553813,
0.0141762, 0.0254432, -0.0124213, -0.0220576, 0.0278842, 0.00114805,
-0.013759, 0.00493565, -0.0146888, -0.00463272, -0.0332577, -0.0200095,
0.00230828, -0.0232427, 0.00433733, -0.0244282, -0.0245909, 0.0155191,
0.00425367, 0.00868522, -0.0347233, 0.00191488, -0.0154211, 0.0154046,
-0.00126067, 0.00826277, -0.0124104, -0.0136281, -0.023651, 0.00853699,
-0.0373163, 0.0147421, -0.0425991, -0.0198727, -0.0197213, -0.0115728,
-0.0127898), C2 = c(0.00450319, 0.00394058, -0.0316527, 0.00310475,
0.016075, 0.0108606, 0.0195024, -0.0109932, 0.02644, 0.00177053,
-0.0180791, -0.0128455, -0.0353571, 0.00868615, 0.0278649, -0.0143205,
0.0198699, 0.00600335, 0.00636933, -0.0245385, 0.0247255, -0.0019047,
0.00418658, -0.0106317, 0.0329249, -0.0490193, -0.0322256, -0.00525161,
0.0127281, -0.0210357, 0.048556, -0.0157994, 0.0225328, 0.0420733,
-0.0722942, 0.0117474, -0.00108231, -0.053874, -0.0351118, 0.000781904,
-0.0188162, -0.0214653, 0.0150199, 0.0339645, -0.0335628, -0.0151206,
0.0163763, -0.015727, -0.0232298, 0.0172519, 0.0348876, -0.026288,
0.0383726, -0.018123, 0.0200251, -0.0246757, 0.0184051, 0.0249351,
-0.00324928, 0.0129067, -0.0143993, -0.00150337, -0.00089652,
-0.0477761, 0.00873251, -0.0184572, 0.00115896, 0.0252723, -0.0188119,
0.0403222, -0.00957213, -0.0280059, 0.0183744, -0.025548, 0.021987,
0.0268481, -0.0267149, 0.00712551, -0.0115199, 0.00559716, 0.00779719,
-0.0181187, -0.0182654, -0.0263084, 0.00126466, 0.0397802, 0.0457278,
0.0098323, -0.00865206, 0.0248558, -0.0163334, 0.00451314, 0.0337946,
0.0267819)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -94L))
```

The `Database_ID` and `Profile` columns in the `ann` dataframe (there are other columns in the `ann` dataframe...refer to below)

```
> dput(ann[c("Database_ID","Profile")])
structure(list(Database_ID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13",
"AC14", "AC15", "AC17", "AC18", "AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21",
"AC22", "AC23", "AC24", "AC25", "AC26", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2",
"AC30", "AC31", "AC32", "AC33", "AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC37",
"AC38", "AC39", "AC3", "AC40", "AC41", "AC42", "AC43", "AC45",
"AC46", "AC47", "AC48", "AC49", "AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53",
"AC54", "AC55", "AC56", "AC57", "AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61",
"AC62", "AC63", "AC64", "AC65", "AC66", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6",
"AC70", "AC71", "AC72", "AC73", "AC74", "AC75", "AC76", "AC77",
"AC78", "AC79", "AC7", "AC80", "AC81", "AC82", "AC83", "AC84",
"AC86", "AC87", "AC88", "AC89", "AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC92",
"AC9", "AC100", "AC101", "AC102", "AC103", "AC104", "AC105",
"AC16", "AC68", "AC93", "AC94", "AC95", "AC96", "AC97", "AC99",
"DE10", "DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", "DE16", "DE17", "DE18",
"DE19", "DE1", "DE20", "DE21", "DE22", "DE23", "DE25", "DE26",
"DE27", "DE2", "DE33", "DE34", "DE35", "DE36", "DE37", "DE38",
"DE39", "DE3", "DE40", "DE41", "DE42", "DE44", "DE45", "DE46",
"DE47", "DE48", "DE49", "DE4", "DE50", "DE51", "DE52", "DE53",
"DE54", "DE55", "DE56", "DE57", "DE58", "DE59", "DE60", "DE7",
"DE9", "DE29", "DE30", "DE32", "DE43", "DE5"), Profile = c("Schiz.",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.",
"Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "BP", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Dep.",
"BP", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.")), row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35",
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46",
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57",
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68",
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79",
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90",
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100",
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109",
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118",
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127",
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136",
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145",
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153"), class = "data.frame")
```

There are other columns in `ann`, which I don't need.

```
> dput(head(ann))
structure(list(Database_ID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13",
"AC14", "AC15"), Collection_type = c("Array", "Array", "Array",
"Array", "Array", "Array"), Age = c(40L, 51L, 19L, 49L, 48L,
44L), Round_Age = c(40L, 50L, 20L, 50L, 50L, 45L), sex = c("M",
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), race = c("White", "White", "White",
"White", "White", "White"), Profile = c("Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "BP", "Unaffected control"), DSM_IV = c(295.9, 295.9, 295.9,
296.44, 296.7, NA), Axis_I_Primary_Dx = c("SCHIZ UNDIFF", "SCHIZ UNDIFF",
"SCHIZ UNDIFF", "BP I", "BP I", "CONTROL"), PMI = c(34L, 43L,
28L, 19L, 18L, 28L), Brain_PH = c(6.18, 6.63, 6.73, 5.87, 6.5,
6.59), Left_Brain = c("Fixed", "Frozen", "Frozen", "Fixed", "Frozen",
"Fixed"), Suicide_Status = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"
), Psychotic_Feature = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Unknown",
"No"), Rate_Of_Death = c("Possible anoxia at death (e.g., CO poisoning or pneumonia)",
"Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden"), Exacerbation = c("No evidence of exacerbation",
"No evidence of exacerbation", "No evidence of exacerbation",
"Definite", "No evidence of exacerbation", "Unknown"), Smoking_At_TOD = c("Yes",
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Unknown"), Lifetime_Alcohol_Use = c("Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)",
"Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)",
"Social (1?2 drinks/day)", "Little or none (less than 1 drink/day)",
"Social (1?2 drinks/day)", "Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)"
), Lifetime_Drug_Use = c("Moderate drug use in present", "Social",
"Heavy drug use in present", "Little or none", "Moderate drug use in present",
"Little or none"), Lifetime_Antipsychotics = c(75000L, 130000L,
2500L, 4000L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
"6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, we may need to `recode` before doing the `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
ann %>%
    select(FID = Database_ID, Indication = Profile) %>% 
    mutate(Indication = recode(Indication, 
      "Unaffected control" = "0/1", "BP" = "1/2")) %>% 
    inner_join(dat, ., by = "FID")
```

-output

```
   FID IID SOL         C1          C2 Indication
1 AC13   1   0 -0.0285172  0.00450319        1/2
2 AC14   1   0 -0.0422061  0.00394058        1/2
3 AC15   1   0 -0.0135105 -0.03165270        0/1
```

Comment: `> phenocov <- ann %>% select(FID=Database_ID,Indication=Profile) %>% mutate(Indication=recode(Indication,"Unaffected control"="0/1", "BP"="1/2")) %>% inner_join(dat, .)` return empty rows.

Comment: @melolili I used the dput of 'ann' from your last dput as input i.e. from `dput(head(ann))`

Comment: @melolili what is the output from `ann %>%
    select(FID = Database_ID, Indication = Profile) %>% 
    mutate(Indication = recode(Indication, 
      "Unaffected control" = "0/1", "BP" = "1/2"))`

Comment: `> head(phenocov)
   FID Indication
1 AC10     Schiz.
2 AC11     Schiz.
3 AC12     Schiz.
4 AC13        1/2
5 AC14        1/2
6 AC15        0/1`

Comment: @melolili you said it is returning empty rows, but now you are showing head that is not empty?

Comment: By removing the `inner_join(dat, .)`, its no longer empty

Comment: @melolili That means your `dat`  may not have matching 'FID' although your `dput` of dat is working fine for me

Comment: @melolili Are you using the same dput data showed in your post for testing

Comment: @melolili what is the output of `sum(dat$FID %in% ann$Database_ID)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243096/discussion-between-melolili-and-akrun).